# Cassandra / Eclipse - Can't make connection

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, connection, cassandra

So I'm using Cassandra in my project and I have to make a connection between Eclipse and the data base. I tried to use a JDBC-compliant driver that I found on code.google.com but I'm getting this exception:

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1*

This is my code:

```
package cassandrasampledriver;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.DriverResolverException;
import org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.InvalidUrlException;

 public class CassandraDriver 
{

 public static void main(String[] args)  {
     Connection con = null;
     String KS = "cassandrademocql";

     try 
     {
         Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/" + KS);

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String query = "DROP KEYSPACE cassandrademocql;";
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

     }


     catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please tell us the driver version you are using?

Comment: First of all Thanks for your reply!
I wanna just mention that I'm just starring using Cassandra so I don't know much about it.
I'm using:
DataStax Community Server | Version 1.2.1
Eclipse | Version: Juno Service Release 1
JDK | 6u38 windows x64
JRE6

I hope this will answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code using [this cql driver](http://bit.ly/WQOMvG) (Version 1.1.2 compatible with cassandra 1.2.
on JDK6 without an Error. Maybe you are missing references in your classpath? The only problem with the code is that you are assigning a variable to a method call that wont return anything `ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);` and so a `java.sql.SQLNonTransientException` exception will be thrown.

You said you are new to Cassandra, just some friendly advice, I would do some research on the available [APIs for Cassandra](http://brianoneill.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/cassandra-apis-laundry-list.html) before making a choice.

These are the JARs I used

- apache-cassandra-1.2.0-rc1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- apache-cassandra-clientutil-1.2.0-rc1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- apache-cassandra-thrift-1.2.0-rc1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- cassandra-jdbc-1.1.2.jar libthrift-0.9.0.jar log4j-1.2.16.jar
- log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar

Full code that I ran:

```
package cassandrasampledriver;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CassandraDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
         Connection con = null;
         String KS = "cassandrademocql";

         try 
         {
             Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
             con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/" + KS);

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query = "DROP KEYSPACE cassandrademocql;";

            // Because you are droping the KS this will not return anything
            // So the result set will be null and a java.sql.SQLNonTransientException exception will be thrown every time.
            ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

         }


         catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help !
I really appreciate it :)